# What would you call the child of a god and a demigod?

Tags: mythology, percy-jackson, the-heroes-of-olympus

So if the child of a god and mortal is a demigod, and the children of demigods are called legacies (or demigods), then what would the child of a god and demigod be called? They would be three quarter god and only one quarter human so would they still be a demigod or something else?

Comment: [Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh) -- Oh, wait.  That's 2/3rds and 1/3rd.

Comment: A little semi-demi mini god?

Comment: Whatever they wanted — I’d rather not find out what an offended offspring of a god does.

Answer (score 7):

They would still be a legacy, or possibly a demigod.

The [wikia states](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy)

> A legacy is any mortal who is a second or further generation descendant of a god. They may or may not possess similar abilities to their godly ancestors.

For demigod

> Demigods, or half-bloods, are a race of beings who are half-mortal, half-god. They possess mortal souls and are vulnerable to old age and death;

So the demigod in question is a direct result of a god/mortal pairing. No matter how far you go down the line, that person will always have mortal DNA. So, most likely a legacy since any kids would be 2nd generation from the demigods parents, or possibly a demigod.

It isn't spelled out, so I look at it as being a legacy, since it's not the first god/mortal pairing in the mix.

Comment: The real question is whether mortality is a dominant or a recessive allele.

Comment: I agree, but I think I lean a little bit more towards demigod than legacy. My thoughts: A demigod is god/mortal (i.e. 100% god and 100% mortal). The situation here is god/demigod (i.e. 100% god and 50% god). This seems to me, if anything, this offspring is even more god than a demigod. Therefore, at the very least this child should be a demigod.

Comment: @Odin1806 - Possibly, but that would be a new classification. The wikia (at least) says that a child of a demigod is called a legacy. It doesn't make a provision for how much of a demigod s/he actually is.

Comment: @EricDraven - Like I said, I agree. I just feel that if this is a child of a god and demigod he is more god than a demigod from the start and should be considered at least a demigod; given the current classifications. That's all.

Comment: The child of a god and a demigod would be a first generation descendant of a god. They would also be a second generation descendant (on the demigod's side), but I would think the fact that they are a first generation descendant of a god would tend to rule here.

Comment: @user91895 "No matter how far you go down the line, that person will always have mortal DNA." Well, no. DNA is not infinitely divisible, and it is not transmitted in exact halves from each parent. No one carries genes from ALL of our ancestors. So, "...what would the odds be that you'd get no DNA from one of your great, great, great grandparents? With a few assumptions, it would be about 1 in 8." It is even possible (but very unlikely) for a person to have no DNA from one of his or her grandparents. Source: https://genetics.thetech.org/ask/ask445

Answer (score 1):

### They'd be demigods

(Based on the only in-universe evidence)

First of all, it's not even necessary for a person to have a godly parent to be a demigod. Titans can have demigod children too.

> When she was young, her dad, Hypseus (possibly aka the Hipster), became king of the Lapiths. His grandfather was Oceanus, the Titan of the seas, which proves that **Titans can have demigod children**. And Hypseus’s dad was a river spirit. With those two godly connections, it’s no wonder that Cyrene’s body was made up of more than sixty percent water.
>
> <sub>*(Percy Jackson and the Greek Heroes: Cyrene Punches a Lion)*</sub>

While Cyrene herself would probably be considered as a legacy (Oceanus was her great-grandfather), her kids weren't legacies.

> **Apollo** and the huntress Cyrene had two sons together.

> She was in the mood for something different, and **Ares** is about as different from Apollo as you can get. Cyrene stayed with the war god for many months. Together they had a son named Diomedes, who became the king of Thrace – a country even further north and twice as harsh as Thessaly.

> ‘I know.’ Cyrene felt relieved. **She’d had three demigod children with two different gods**. She’d done more in her life than most people ever got to do, certainly more than most women of her time. She was ready for some peace and quiet.
>
> <sub>*(Percy Jackson and the Greek Heroes: Cyrene Punches a Lion)*</sub>

Her children are clearly specified as demigods, because they had a godly parent. It looks like if you've got a godly parent, then it doesn't matter if your mortal parent was a demigod, legacy or a regular mortal; you're a demigod.

Answer (score 0):

a child of a demigod and a god would be a 3/4 god. 75 percent god. since they are closer to being immortal. they will live longer then normal https://earth8000.fandom.com/wiki/Cyrus_Romella
he is a 3 quarter god and naturally more powerful then a regular demigod. the exact powers and power level is based off the combination ex:  3 quarter god of Poseidon and zues means this will be literally the most powerful near god ever. far stronger and can control lightning and water likely able to combine the two when he or she attacks half half as much mortal dna meaning higher resitance to mortal sickness and disease. ages slower and naturally healthier especially having good genes. will half vampires for example stop aging after reaching adult hood. hunters of artemis dont age because they gain the blessing of artmis. eiher by magic, genes, or blessing, 3 quater gods may stop aging after reaching adult hood. a disavantage to this is they will attract more monsters then a half blood naturally to a higher degree. it will be harder to kill a 3/4 god however. they may or may not posses some default powers that all gods can use or even survive the true presence of a god.

Comment: You talk a lot about powers and power levels in this answer, but that's not what the question was asking about. The question was asking what such a being should be _called_. If you're going to post something using the 'Your Answer' box, please focus on answering the question, not on providing a related commentary. If you just want to post a related commentary, you need to earn a bit more reputation to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] center to learn more.

Comment: The question is also asking about the demigods/gods within the *Percy Jackson* universe, not just generally